Vectorization of power law fitting
I am moving a code base to run using PyTorch tensor on GPU. For loops are terrible on GPU especially for small-sized data. I am trying to vectorize the function below, i.e. to have no for loops.
I need help with Ds[] specifically.
Once I have the vectorized numpy version, converting to tensors should be straightforward.
import numpy

data = np.array( [ [ 11, 2, 3, 40, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ] )

for i, xmin in enumerate( data[:-1] ):
    n = float( N - i )
    alpha = 1 + n / ( np.sum( log_data[i:] )  - n * log_data[i] )
    alphas[i] = alpha
    if alpha > 1:
        print( i, 1 - ( data[i:] / xmin ) ** ( -alpha + 1 ) )
        Ds[i] = np.max( np.abs( 
            1 - (data[i:] / xmin) ** (-alpha + 1)   # Theoretical CDF\
              - np.arange( n ) / n                  #      Actual CDF
        ))

sigmas = ( alphas - 1 ) / np.sqrt( N - np.arange( N - 1 ) )

I was trying to implement this step by step. But it seems the second term np.arange(n) / n is wrong
import numpy as np

def fit_power_law(data):
    # Assuming 'data' is already a NumPy array
    logdata = np.log(data)
    N = len(data)

    # Compute cumulative sums from the end
    sums = np.cumsum(logdata[::-1])[::-1]

    # Create array of n values
    ns = np.arange(N, 0, -1, dtype=np.float64)

    # Compute alphas
    alphas = 1 + ns / (sums - ns * logdata)

    # Filter alphas to only include those > 1
    valid_indices = alphas > 1
    filtered_alphas = alphas[valid_indices]
    filtered_data = data[valid_indices]

    M = len(filtered_data)

    # Create a matrix of NaNs
    matrix = np.full((M, M), np.nan)

    # Create an index array for broadcasting
    idx = np.arange(M)
    shifted_indices = idx[:, None] + idx

    # Mask to avoid out-of-bound indices
    mask = shifted_indices < M

    # Fill the matrix with the appropriate values
    matrix[mask] = filtered_data[shifted_indices[mask]]

    # Divide each row by the data array
    tt = matrix / filtered_data[:, np.newaxis]

    # Calculate the first term  [1 - (data[i:] / xmin) ** (-alpha + 1)]
    first_term = 1 - tt ** (-filtered_alphas[:, np.newaxis] + 1)

    
    # Reverse the filtered data array
    data_reversed = filtered_data

    # Create a range array and a mask
    range_array = np.arange(int(data.shape[0]))    
    mask = range_array < data_reversed[:, np.newaxis]

    # Create the result array
    result = np.where(mask, range_array, np.nan)


    # Calculate the length of each inner array (excluding NaNs)
    lengths = np.sum(~np.isnan(result), axis=1)

    # Ensure lengths are at least 1 to avoid division by zero
    lengths = np.maximum(lengths, 1)

    # Broadcast lengths to match the shape of result for division
    lengths_broadcast = lengths[:, np.newaxis]

    # np.arange(n) / n #This is wrong
    second_term = np.where(~np.isnan(result), result / lengths_broadcast, np.nan)

    # Calculate the difference
    min_answer = first_term - second_term

    # Return the maximum absolute difference
    ds = np.nanmax(np.abs(min_answer), axis=1)[:-1]


    alphas = alphas[:-1]

    sigma = (alphas - 1) / np.sqrt(N - np.arange(N - 1, dtype=np.float64))

    ds_final = np.zeros(N-1, dtype=np.float64)

    ds_final[valid_indices] = ds

    return ds_final, alphas, sigma



Can you modify the code so it can be reproducible? Like for example initializing the required variables to random values (with the right distribution which certainly matters to know how many time the conditional if alpha > 1 is taken) using the right dtype and shape.

Note that for such a code, I expect tools like Cython or Numba to be the way to go as vectorizing this seems non-trivial and possibly inefficient in the end (for example, if the condition is often not taken). Can you use them and/or did you tried them?

@JérômeRichard I want to convert it to Pytorch and run it on GPU. Once I have the vectorized numpy version, converting to tensors should be straightforward.

You can't 'vectorizethe max on variable size arrays produced bynp.abs( 1 - (data[i:] / xmin) ** (-alpha + 1) -  np.arange(n) / n. ufunclike np.max have anaccumulatemethod,  but that takes an array argument, not a function.  So you can't rewite that as a single call to a numpy method that handles all ofdata`. You may speed up the loop a bit  by precalculating pieces of it.
